# SignaturePad not defined - can not initialise signature_pad module into script

Tags: javascript, node.js, signaturepad

I'm having an issue using the npm module - signature_pad, and can't seem to get it set up. At the moment all I am using is vanilla HTML, CSS and JS. At the moment I keep getting an error saying: `SignaturePad is not defined`. I tried importing the module from my package.JSON file using `import SignaturePad from 'signature_pad'` but I get an error back saying `unexpected token import`.

I have attached my HTML and JS code below. Any suggestions?

JavaScript

```js
var wrapper1 = document.getElementById("signature-pad-1"),
    canvas1 = wrapper1.querySelector("canvas"),
    signaturePad1;

resizeCanvas(canvas1);
signaturePad1 = new SignaturePad(canvas1);

function resizeCanvas(canvas) {
   var ratio =  window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
   canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
   canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
   canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
}
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sign Here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contract">
      <h1>Signature Below</h1>
      <p>ABC</p>
      <div id="signature-pad-1" class="m-signature-pad">
        <div class="m-signature-pad--body">
          <canvas></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/sig_pad.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/1.5.3/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved. Swapping the order of the scripts around and making the signature_pad.min.js script first seems to have fixed it.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/1.5.3/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/sig_pad.js"></script>
```